# Getting NaN values from the model using FMPy

Tags: python, simulation, fmi, siemens-nx

I’m running an FMU export from Simcenter that runs on 5e-7 step-size in FMPy. However, after a few steps the FMU starts returning NaN values. My expectation is that this is due to the way I am using FMPy, but I am unable to solve it until now.

1. Which variables within FMPy should I use, considering the use-case (read below)?
2. Anybody who has had NaN values, and knows how to solve this?

The FMU from Simcenter runs on a container within Azure, and receives input from and sends output to a local Simulink model. There’s basically a recurrent feedback loop between the two models. For my project, I need to run the FMU only for 1 step at a time, return result to Simulink and keep FMU active for future input that would simulate the FMU further. (for implementation of running FMU 1 step at a time with FMPy I’m using continue_simulation.py example from https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/main/fmpy/examples/continue_simulation.py.)

The local Simulink model and the Simcenter model run on different step-sizes. Therefore, we have included a rate-transition within the Simulink model. When we run the FMU directly within Simulink, this runs as expected. However, once I change the FMU into a Matlab function block, which is rerouted to the container on our platform, it starts returning NaN values.

Currently have the following variables configured within FMPY simulate_fmu():

```
filename
model_description
fmu_instance
input
initialize=False
start_time=0 (will be 5e-7 next run)
stop_time=5e-7 (will be 1e-6 next run)
step_size=5e-7
terminate=False
set_stop_time=False
```

The issue I’m facing now is when using 5e-7 step-size and 5e-7 stop-time, the FMU starts returning drastically different values comparing to same FMU running in Simulink from the 7th step and on the 10th step reaches NaN values as outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was to stop using simulate_fmu() function that does quite some things under the hood and instead use the functions, that simulate_fmu() uses, myself to avoid using extra things that I did not need (also helped to better understand how FMPy works). This resulted in the model returning expected values and not NaN values anymore.

I used the example code from custom_input.py FMPy docs (https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/main/fmpy/examples/custom_input.py)

My custom function to run a step(s) of FMU now looks like this:

```
def set_input(self, inputs_array_values, step_size, interval):
    # Proceed with running the step(s)
    stop_time = self._current_simulation_time + interval
    while self._current_simulation_time < stop_time:
        # set the input
        print(f"value references: {self._vrs_inputs.values()}, input values: {inputs_array_values}")
        self._fmu.setReal(self._vrs_inputs.values(), inputs_array_values)
        # perform one step
        self._fmu.doStep(currentCommunicationPoint=self._current_simulation_time, communicationStepSize=step_size)
        # advance the time
        self._current_simulation_time += interval
        print(f"current simulation time: {self._current_simulation_time}")

    # return without delay. 1 step delay will be created in Simulink as Unit Delay is required to properly run the simulation by fixing algebraic loop
    outputs = []
    outputs = self._fmu.getReal(self._vrs_outputs.values())
    outputs.insert(0, float(self._current_simulation_time))
    row = tuple(outputs)
    self._results.append(str(row))

    return row
```